# UnZip files after install with InnoUnzip - Error "Invalid prototype"

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

unpacker I found what I was looking for, he should unpack the files after installation
This is [InnoUnzip.ZIP](http://www.scriptkitties.com/innounzip/)

My installer folder looks like this:

[image]

My code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "unzipper.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Somefile.zip"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: ExtractMe('{app}\Somefile.zip', '{app}');

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"

[Code]
procedure unzip(src, target: AnsiString);
external 'unzip@files:unzipper.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure ExtractMe(src, target : AnsiString); - ERROR HERE!!!!!
begin
  unzip(ExpandConstant(src), ExpandConstant(target));
end;
```

Text error: **Invalid prototype for "Extract Me"**

Comment: You are using Unicode Inno Setup which expects a Unicode string for that `AfterInstall` prototype. Use this `procedure ExtractMe(src, target: string);`. Then when you'll be passing those params to the plugin typecast `unzip(AnsiString(ExpandConstant(src)), AnsiString(ExpandConstant(target)));`. Anyway, that plugin is a bit *lazy* and I believe that the whole its code could be executed directly from Inno Setup script.

Answer (score 6):

Following up TLama's point about the redundancy of the DLL: the same effect can be achieved simply by coding `UnZip()` directly within the Inno Setup script.

```
const
  SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX = 4;
  SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL = 16;

procedure Unzip(ZipFile, TargetFolder: String); 
var
  ShellObj, SrcFile, DestFolder: Variant;
begin
  ShellObj := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
  SrcFile := ShellObj.NameSpace(ZipFile);
  DestFolder := ShellObj.NameSpace(TargetFolder);
  DestFolder.CopyHere(SrcFile.Items, SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX or SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL)
end;

procedure ExtractMe(src, target : String); 
begin
  // Add extra application code here, then:
  Unzip(ExpandConstant(src), ExpandConstant(target));
end;
```

The Inno Setup script code is more or less the same as the DLL's... only a bit shorter.

Be aware that if Zip or Destination folder don't exist, the `NameSpace()` method calls return a `Null`, the `CopyHere()` fails, and the user sees a rude and baffling dialog - so best to check before calling.

Comment: I used your code in an installer on Windows 10, it worked like a charm, thank you. However, it doesn't work on Windows 7. The installation completes with no errors, but the zip is not extracted. I checked in the innosetup compiler and all the variables have the correct values. Everything appears identical to my tests on Windows 10. Any idea, what the problem could be?

Comment: @Dulkan: I have tested this under W7 and W8 and it worked ok on both (I remember because W8 can produce a sexy progress graph while it unzips, and W7 a much less sexy dialog). So I am baffled. It should go. If you run it showing the progress box, do you see anything?

This approach depends on the shell's ability to extract Zips - I take it this is all functioning fine on the target W7 machine? For example, a broken copy of WinZip might kill it, I guess?

Comment: Hmm, this may be. The Win7 machine uses WinRAR and is a bare bones test machine, which is frequently formatted. Possibly the basic winzip is not installed there? With the progress box, nothing happens as well, the installation finishes immediately after setup installed the zip-file in the directory.

Comment: @Dulkan: A bare bones machine is fine. But what I suspect is happening is that WinRAR is taking unto itself zip expansion tasks normally handled by Explorer, and is then cocking them up. Can you test your installer on a clean W7 machine?

Comment: I tried it on a Win10 machine again, no WinRAR or anything similar installed there and the installer exhibited the exact same behaviour. I have several theories. 1)The file supplied to me is now a rar instead of a zip, I simply renamed it to zip, as the installer throws an exception, when I supply a rar-file. 2) Currently I have no access to write and compile the installer on the win10 64bit machine. I did so on a win7 32-bit machine. Could this cause some issues? Either way, the solution appears fairly fragile to me. Though I am baffled, as at the start it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Dulkan: Explanation 1) is the correct one: RAR archives are not supported by Windows shell. The solution only works for zips. Renaming it is not the same thing at all. If you want to use another archive format, you'll need an alternative approach. The robustness of my solution (and, by the way, also the original UnZipper dll approach) is indeed limited by the requirement that the target machine has working shell zip support. This seems modest to me, but YMMV.

Comment: This works great for the install by using `AfterInstall: ExtractMe(...)`. When uninstalling, however, only the source zip file is removed. Is there any way to mark the extracted files for uninstall?

Comment: @Samuel - Not that I know of. You'd have to put something together to do the tidying up in the UninstallRun section. Perhaps worth asking as a separate question?

Answer (score 1):

Change the parameter type AnsiString to String.